# Creating a Cygwin emacs macro

Tags: windows, emacs, cygwin

I have been [researching how to get Cygwin to work under emacs](https://superuser.com/questions/61605/running-cygwin-inferior-shell-in-emacs).  I have it working, but now I want to write a macro that will do the following:

- Launch by typing M-x cygwin
- Have the script stored in some obvious place (probably my .emacs file)
- M-x shell
- Rename the buffer to cygwin (or cygwin1, cygwin2, cygwin3, ... if cygwin exists) probably using M-x rename-buffer
- M-x ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on
- M-x set-buffer-process-coding-system 'undecided-unix 'undecided-unix
- Open and run cygwin

It will basically do all of the above steps.  I think most of the organization for this little project is done.  How do I tie it all together so I can just type M-x cygwin and see a happy new cygwin buffer?  What exactly needs to be added to .emacs?  Also, where exactly is .emacs in Windows?

I still want the ability to run M-x shell for the windows shell for now.  I may also make similar macros for MSYS and ssh'ing to my Linux boxes.  How do I get started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many questions, here are some answers:

Your .emacs can exist many places, it depends, read [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InitFile).  In short try <kbd>C-x C-f .emacs</kbd>, or check the value of the variable `'user-init-file` (<kbd>C-h v user-init-file</kbd>).

I think the command you want is something along the lines of this:

```
(require 'comint) ; this does require comint
(defun cygwin ()
  "do what i want for cygwin"
  (interactive)
  (let ((buffer (get-buffer-create (generate-new-buffer-name "cygwin"))))
    (pop-to-buffer buffer)
    (unless (comint-check-proc buffer)
      (apply 'make-comint-in-buffer (buffer-name buffer) buffer "c:/cygwin/Cygwin.bat"
             nil
             nil)
      (ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on)
      (set-buffer-process-coding-system 'undecided-unix 'undecided-unix))))
```

*Note:* I directly ran the process `Cygwin.bat` instead of running shell and then starting that batch program.  I believe the effect is the same, and more straight forward.  I did choose the easy way out for naming the buffer (using `'generate-new-buffer-name`) - you'll want to customize to what you want.

You can dump the above command in your .emacs easiest by doing the <kbd>C-x C-f .emacs</kbd> and pasting it in the buffer that gets opened up.  Save it and restart (or do <kbd>M-x eval-defun</kbd> when your cursor is in the body of that command.  Then <kbd>M-x cygwin</kbd> will run the command.